# How to use strtok to read a 3x3 matrix - I used flex but I'm not sure submitting pre-processed source is allowed

Tags: c, file-io

I've always avoided strtok like the plague, I only use the *scanf family when I am being quick-n-dirty.

flex isn't hard, it's just this:

```
%{
double entries[9];
int position = 0;
int error = 0;
%}

%%
-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? {if(position == 9) { error = 1; } else { sscanf(yytext,"%lf",entries[position]); position++; } }
\n {}
\r {}
\t {}
. {}
%%
```

Then I use include to create one larger code file (we can only submit the one) and I plan to submit the pre-processed source code (this will contain line-macros and still give useful/nice errors - if present, to GCCs credit!) but it wont look nice.

It seems the lecturer wants us to use strtok! So I did some reading and found: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ I don't feel bad for avoiding this.

I've learnt a lesson here, when you have had jobs programming in C++, when you have experience programming, don't think an "introductory module" will be easy points.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm not sure on the format of the input file, it seems to show 3 rows of numbers, numbers separated by spaces, this is all well and good but is it \n or that other one (or \r\n I think for windows?)

Ah good, someone has already asked this! [Reading a 3x3 Matrix from a file an then displaying it in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737327/reading-a-3x3-matrix-from-a-file-an-then-displaying-it-in-c) so I have an answer of how to do this. None the less please help me with strtok? I feel I should be able to jump through the hoops in such a module.

Comment: The input file has a the format of float (or double, as you like) numbers separated by spaces or new lines. If you read more than 9 numbers, you have an error.

Comment: And it's not clear to me, what do you want to use `strtok()` for?

Comment: @fvdalcin I think I have to, I want to use flex, I posted that to show I could actually do it.

Comment: If you have to use `strtok`, maybe you could rewrite your own version which doesn't have global state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me, do you want to fill a 3x3 matrix avoiding the use of `strtok`?

Build your own function, is easy using `strtod`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "1.1 2.1 3.1\r\n1.2 2.2 3.2\n1.3 2.3 3.3", *p = s;
    double data[3][3];
    int i = 0, n = 9;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[0][i] = strtod(p, &p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Works with both `\n` and `\r\n` because `strtod` discards whitespace and `isspace` characters.

Comment: Sorry reflex accept because it looked like it was good, that's C++, this is C.

Comment: You are free to accept what you want, but this code works with c and c++ :)

Comment: It doesn't compile with C90 certainly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see the implementation of strtok function.

[Apple Version](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtok.c.htm)

[Microsoft Version](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtok.c.htm)

The main point, as stated in cplusplus.com, is :

**The point where the last token was found is kept internally by the function to be used on the next call (particular library implementations are not required to avoid data races).**

See the declaration in microsoft version

    `static char *lastToken = NULL; /* UNSAFE SHARED STATE! */`

Comment: What's the stdlib behavior?